# Create difference columns from one hot encoded columns

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction

I'm trying to create some extra features on a data set. I want to get a spatial context from the features I already have one hot encoded. So for example, I have this:

```
    F1    F2    F3    F4
1   0     1     1     0
2   1     0     1     1
3   1     0     0     0
4   0     0     0     1
```

I want to create some new columns against the values here:

```
    F1    F2    F3    F4    S1    S2    S3    S4
1   0     1     1     0     0     2     1     0
2   1     0     0     1     1     0     0     3
3   1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
4   0     0     0     1     0     0     0     4
```

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this, to calculate changes from the last value of the column and output that to a corresponding column. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the logic behind the new columns?

Comment: It's just the difference from the last column. So for example Row 1, F1 doesn't have anything, so there's a 0. F1 -> F2 has two spaces counted if the index starts from 1. So on and so forth. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: So why is a 1 in S3?

Comment: F2 -> F3 has a difference of 1. F1 -> F2 has a difference of 2

Comment: its difficult to understand your logic...could you precise...the result in S1 to S4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
def func(x):
    # create result array
    result = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.int)

    # get indices of array distinct of zero
    w = np.argwhere(x).ravel()

    # compute the difference between consecutive indices and add the first index + 1
    array = np.hstack(([w[0] + 1], np.ediff1d(w)))

    # set the values on result
    np.put(result, w, array)

    return result


columns = ['S{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
s = pd.DataFrame(df.ne(0).apply(func, axis=1).values.tolist(),
                 columns=columns)

result = pd.concat([df, s], axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   F1  F2  F3  F4  S1  S2  S3  S4
0   0   1   1   0   0   2   1   0
1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   3
2   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   4
```

Note that you need to import numpy (`import numpy as np`) in order for `func` to work. The idea is to find the indices distinct of zero compute the difference between to consecutive values, set the first value as the `index + 1`, and do this for each row.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I wanted to do!